# How to init a swarm on Windows 7 (as single node) with dynamic IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Windows 7 laptop that I need to make a single node, and the IP address is dynamic. The problem is the following when trying to init the swarm:

From within Docker Quickstart Terminal:

```
$ docker swarm init
Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces (<examples>) - specify on with --advertise-addr

$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.120 
Error response from daemon: must specify a listening address because the address to advertise is not recognized as a system address, and the system's IP address to use could not be uniquely identified

$ docker swarm init  --advertise-addr 192.168.1.120 --listen-addr 192.168.1.120
Error response from daemon: manager stopped: failed to listen on remote API address: listen tcp 192.168.1.120:2377: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

I tried with **127.0.0.1** (both advertise and listen), and that seems to have worked as far as init’ing the swarm. Would using the loopback have any negative/side effects for accessing the containers, though? I can’t seem to access anything via their mapped ports in the compose file.

For instance, trying to access Portainer fails (not found), but it seems to be running just fine according to the logs:

```
docker service ls
ID                  NAME                    MODE               REPLICAS           IMAGE                       PORTS
0ugklcrsxtw7        portainer_portainer     replicated         1/1                portainer/portainer:latest  *:4321->9000/tcp

docker service logs 0ugklcrsxtw7
portainer_portainer.1.vom7rarh9ccn@default    | 2018/02/07 20:37:45 Starting Portainer 1.16.1 on :9000
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: ‘3’
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    ports:
      - "4321:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer:/data

volumes:
  portainer:
```

I'd like to init a swarm on an interface, instead of an IP that will most likely change.  How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker Toolbox uses VirtualBox to start VM's with docker preinstalled.

`docker-machine ls` should show you the "default" machine that the quickstart terminal creates when you first open it.

As long as this VM is using its default config in VirtualBox, it should have the private IP of `192.168.99.100`

If you have other VM's in VirtualBox (you can create many docker nodes with `docker-machine create <some-name>`) then make sure to start them in the same order with `docker-machine start <name>` or in the VirtualBox GUI, as it will give out IP's starting with 100 and go up.

Comment: So you're saying that `advertise-addr` and `listen-addr` should be set to `192.168.99.100` when creating a swarm on the host?

Comment: `docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.120 --listen-addr 192.168.99.100:2376` returns `Error resonse from daemon: manager stopped: failed to listen on remote API address: listen tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: bind: address already in use`

Comment: you don't need to specify listen-addr, it's optional and will default to advertise-addr.

Comment: Bret, first, thanks for taking the time to help me. I much appreciate it.  Ok, if you check out the first group of commands, `docker swarm init` was tried without `advertise-addr`, with only `advertise-addr`, and with both `advertise-addr` and `listen-addr` - none of which worked - resulting in daemon errors in all 3 cases. I'm at a loss here.  I will append my question above with the output from `ipconfig` once I have access to that machine again (in a couple hours).  Perhaps docker is confused because of multiple interfaces (wired & wireless), but specifying the wired IP didn't resolve it.

Comment: ah, I think I got it.  Docker is running in the VM on Windows 7. That's the confusing part.  I'm used to testing on Linux.  `docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100` worked perfectly.  Thanks for helping me think about this!

Comment: You're welcome!  Also check your docker versions. Toolbox doesn't autoupdate and should be client/server 17.12 or 18.01 for `docker version` at this point. Usually, a failed `swarm init` will give you IP and eth options in error message with later versions.